# my offer letter says "this offer is valid, subject to your clearing the reference check".

Tags: job-offer

my offer letter says "this offer is valid, subject to your clearing the reference check". what does it mean? Reference check was done or it will be done after the acceptance of offer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about English than the workplace - probably a better fit on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7):

It's straightforward.  They've made you an offer.  If you accept they will take up your references.  If nothing bad comes out you're good to go, but if they don't like something in the references they reserve the right to withdraw the offer.

Answer (score 2):

The offer is valid until and unless your reference check unearths a deal breaker about you, at which point the offer is rescinded/withdrawn unless you come up with and fire off a good explanation.